# Gerar um novo JSON apartir manipulando os dados de outro JSON

Tags: javascript, json, web-service, javascript-eventos

Estava participando de um teste para estágio e me foi proposto o seguinte problema:

Eu teria que ler o JSON abaixo:

```
[ 
{ "nome":"Jabba, the Hutt", "jedi":false, "sistemas":[ "Tatooine" ] },
{ "nome":"Chewbacca", "jedi":false, "sistemas":[ "Kashyyk" ] },
{ "nome":"Han", "jedi":false, "sistemas":[ "Tatooine", "Coruscant" ] },
{ "nome":"Leia", "jedi":true, "sistemas":[ "Alderaan", "Endor" ] },
{ "nome":"Luke", "jedi":true, "sistemas":[ "Tatooine", "Dagobah" ] },
{ "nome":"Yoda", "jedi":true, "sistemas":[ "Kashyyk", "Dagobah" ] },
{ "nome":"Obi-Wan", "jedi":true, "sistemas":[ "Coruscant", "Mustaphar" ] },
{ "nome":"Darth Vader", "jedi":false, "sistemas":[ "Tatooine", "Mustaphar" ] }]
```

E teria que criar um novo JSON que ficaria algo tipo isso:

```
[{"nome": Darth Vader, "contato":["Luke", "Leia" ....]},{}]
```

Seria um JSON que teria em cada campo o nome do personagem e um array que seria os contatos.

Agora a condição para um personagem entrar no array de contatos de um outro personagem é:

- que esse personagem não seja o mesmo personagem do campo nome
- 2 personagens podem de contatos entre eles se ambos forem "jedi":true OU se tiverem algum sistema em comum. Por exemplo o Jabba, the Hutt vai ser contato de Han porque ambos tem Tatooine em seus arrays no campo sistemas.

Esse é meu código:

```
var v = [ 
{ "nome":"Jabba, the Hutt", "jedi":false, "sistemas":[ "Tatooine" ] },
{ "nome":"Chewbacca", "jedi":false, "sistemas":[ "Kashyyk" ] },
{ "nome":"Han", "jedi":false, "sistemas":[ "Tatooine", "Coruscant" ] },
{ "nome":"Leia", "jedi":true, "sistemas":[ "Alderaan", "Endor" ] },
{ "nome":"Luke", "jedi":true, "sistemas":[ "Tatooine", "Dagobah" ] },
{ "nome":"Yoda", "jedi":true, "sistemas":[ "Kashyyk", "Dagobah" ] },
{ "nome":"Obi-Wan", "jedi":true, "sistemas":[ "Coruscant", "Mustaphar" ] },
{ "nome":"Darth Vader", "jedi":false, "sistemas":[ "Tatooine", "Mustaphar" ] }];

function verificaSist(){
    var verifica = false;
    for(var i in arguments[0]){
        for(var b in arguments[1]){
            if(arguments[0][i]===arguments[1][b]){
                verifica = true;
                break;      
            }   
        }
        if(verifica == true){
            break;
        }
    }
    if(verifica == true){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

  }

function criaAgenda(v){
  var agenda=[];
  var contato = []
  for(var personagem1 of v){
    for(var personagem2 of v){
        var sist = [personagem1.sistemas, personagem2.sistemas];
        var d = verificaSist.apply(null,sist);

        if(((personagem1.jedi == true && personagem2.jedi==true)|| d == true) && personagem1.nome !== personagem2.nome){
            contato.push(personagem2.nome);
        }
    }
    agenda.push({"nome":personagem1.nome, "contato":contato=[]});

  }
  return JSON.stringify(agenda);
}
console.log(criaAgenda(v));
```

O problema ao meu ver é esse `if`:

```
if(((personagem1.jedi == true && personagem2.jedi==true)|| d == true) && personagem1.nome !== personagem2.nome)
```

Só que não consigo pensar em nada melhor.

Comment: A "Leia" não tem relação com o "Darth Vader": ambos não são "Jedi"  e não possuem sistemas em comum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código em si funcionaria corretamente, exceto pela colocação da array `contato` no lugar errado. O Correto seria redefinir essa array a cada volta do primeiro `for` na função `criaAgenda`:

```
for(var personagem1 of v){
   var contato = [];
   for(var personagem2 of v){
      ...
   }
}
```

E no `agenda.push` informar apenas a array:

```
agenda.push({"nome":personagem1.nome, "contato":contato});
```

Outra coisa são códigos dispensáveis na função `verificaSist()`. Em vez de fazer `break`s, basta retornar `true` quando algo combinar, caso contrário, retornar `false`, sem precisar usar a variável de controle `verifica`.

Ao fazer o `return` na função, o laço já é suspenso sem precisar de `break`. Outras coisas que podem enxugar o código é verificar se a variável é `true` apenas com a própria variável, sem `== true`, por exemplo:

`if(d == true)` é o mesmo que `if(d)` e `if(d == false)` é o mesmo que `if(!d)`

Veja como ficaria a função `verificaSist()` sem excessos e compare com o seu original:

```
function verificaSist(){
   for(var i in arguments[0]){
      for(var b in arguments[1]){
         if(arguments[0][i]===arguments[1][b]) return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Bem mais simples, não?!

**Código em funcionamento:**

```js
var v = [ 
{ "nome":"Jabba, the Hutt",   "jedi":false, "sistemas":[ "Tatooine" ] },
{ "nome":"Chewbacca",         "jedi":false, "sistemas":[ "Kashyyk" ] },
{ "nome":"Han",               "jedi":false, "sistemas":[ "Tatooine", "Coruscant" ] },
{ "nome":"Leia",              "jedi":true,  "sistemas":[ "Alderaan", "Endor" ] },
{ "nome":"Luke",              "jedi":true,  "sistemas":[ "Tatooine", "Dagobah" ] },
{ "nome":"Yoda",              "jedi":true,  "sistemas":[ "Kashyyk", "Dagobah" ] },
{ "nome":"Obi-Wan",           "jedi":true,  "sistemas":[ "Coruscant", "Mustaphar" ] },
{ "nome":"Darth Vader",       "jedi":false, "sistemas":[ "Tatooine", "Mustaphar" ] }];

function verificaSist(){
   for(var i in arguments[0]){
      for(var b in arguments[1]){
         if(arguments[0][i]===arguments[1][b]) return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}

function criaAgenda(v){
  var agenda=[];
  
  for(var personagem1 of v){
    var contato = [];
    for(var personagem2 of v){
        var sist = [personagem1.sistemas, personagem2.sistemas];
        var d = verificaSist.apply(null,sist);

        if( (personagem1.jedi && personagem2.jedi || d) && personagem1.nome !== personagem2.nome){
            contato.push(personagem2.nome);
        }
    }

    agenda.push({"nome":personagem1.nome, "contato":contato});

  }
  return JSON.stringify(agenda);
}

console.log(JSON.parse(criaAgenda(v)));
```